# RPi security - erase data upon compromise

Tags: security, rpi

I have an application-sensitive project with an RPi Zero W.

I would like to set up a self destruct feature, triggered either by hardware or software compromises, that once triggered, securely and quickly erases without leaving any trace, any storage on it leaving no sensitive data anywhere on the device.

How could this be achieved? If it can't, what's the next best solution?

Comment: The trick here is establishing a system that can run from memory while it deletes the root fs, etc.  Not impossible, but there's nothing really Pi specific about it either -- you could try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.